# Command.ExecuteScalar always return null while Stored Procedure in Management Studio runs fine

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures

I have the following SQL stored procedure with one input parameter and one out parameter.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spCanUserEdit]
(
@username nvarchar(255)
)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @CanEdit bit

SELECT
    @CanEdit = CanUserEdit
FROM tblUsers
WHERE username = LOWER(@username)
RETURN SELECT @CanEdit
END
GO
```

In the stored procedure above `CanUserEdit` column in `tblUsers` is bit type column and with default value to 0. Now when I execute this procedure in Management Studio it runs fine but when i use `command.ExecuteScalar()` in my C# code, it always returns `null`. Could anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong here.

Following is my C# method

```
public static bool CanUserEdit(string userName)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[Constants.ConnectionStringName].ConnectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "spCanUserEdit";
            cmd.Connection = conn;

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@username", userName));

            conn.Open();
            bool canEdit = (bool)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

            return canEdit;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is in the way you return data. If you want to use ExecuteScalar, you should not RETURN but instead simply SELECT.

Try to change the SP as following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spCanUserEdit]
(
 @username nvarchar(255)
)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @CanEdit bit

SELECT
    @CanEdit = CanUserEdit
FROM tblUsers
WHERE username = LOWER(@username)

SELECT @CanEdit

RETURN 0
END
GO
```

If you can't change the SP, but the code, the solution is to read parameter '@ReturnValue' with ExecuteNonQuery.

Comment: Thank you very much...It really drove me crazy for a while... couldn't get my head around about this silly mistake. by the way just curious to find out if I really need to Return 0 here ?

Comment: Glad to help :) I've edited my answer to include a possible fix in code instead of SP.

Answer (score 0):

Use a scaler function instead of a stored procedure. SQL functions are much easier to setup and they return a scaler value by default so no 'OUTPUT' or return variable declarations necessary. Example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ScalerFnExample]()
RETURNS VARCHAR(50)
AS
   BEGIN
      RETURN (SELECT TOP 1 Thing FROM Examples.dbo.Stuff)
   END
```

C# Example:

```
    public string SqlScalerFnExample()
    {
        string retVal = default;

        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1;Database=Examples;Trusted_Connection=True;"))
            {
                SqlCommand userFn = new SqlCommand("SELECT dbo.ScalerFnExample()", sqlConnection);

                sqlConnection.Open();

                retVal = (string)userFn.ExecuteScalar();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"SqlScalerFnExample() - Exception: {ex.Message}");
        }

        return retVal;
    }
```